# Error en Docker Composer con Django: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py:437: UserWarning: Engine not recognized from url

Tags: docker, celery

Me sale el siguiente error al querer levantar el contenedor:

```
docker-compose -f dev.yml up
```

Las credenciales, la ip y el puerto están bien.
Ya probamos conectarnos de manera manual: todo jala.
¿Qué puede ser?

```
flower_1                        | Postgres is up - continuing...
celeryworker_low_priority_1     | Postgres is up - continuing...
celeryworker_medium_priority_1  | Postgres is up - continuing...
celerybeat_1                    | celery beat v4.4.0 (cliffs) is starting.
celerybeat_1                    | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py:437: UserWarning: Engine not recognized from url: {'NAME': 'mysql://filasPOS:samuray3@192.168.1.106:3306/filasPOS"', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'ENGINE': ''}
celerybeat_1                    |   warnings.warn("Engine not recognized from url: {0}".format(config))
celeryworker_1                  | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py:437: UserWarning: Engine not recognized from url: {'NAME': 'mysql://filasPOS:samuray3@192.168.1.106:3306/filasPOS"', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'ENGINE': ''}
celeryworker_1                  |   warnings.warn("Engine not recognized from url: {0}".format(config))
flower_1                        | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py:437: UserWarning: Engine not recognized from url: {'NAME': 'mysql://filasPOS:samuray3@192.168.1.106:3306/filasPOS"', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'ENGINE': ''}
flower_1                        |   warnings.warn("Engine not recognized from url: {0}".format(config))
celeryworker_medium_priority_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py:437: UserWarning: Engine not recognized from url: {'NAME': 'mysql://filasPOS:samuray3@192.168.1.106:3306/filasPOS"', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'ENGINE': ''}
celeryworker_medium_priority_1  |   warnings.warn("Engine not recognized from url: {0}".format(config))
celeryworker_low_priority_1     | /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py:437: UserWarning: Engine not recognized from url: {'NAME': 'mysql://filasPOS:samuray3@192.168.1.106:3306/filasPOS"', 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'ENGINE': ''}
celeryworker_low_priority_1     |   warnings.warn("Engine not recognized from url: {0}".format(config))
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu docker-compose? ¿Las credenciales y el puerto de qué cosa está bien?

Comment: mysql://filasPOS:samuray3@192.168.1.106:3306/filasPOS de esta instrucción en específico

Comment: Mi comentario era para que agregaras el archivo a tu pregunta.